# after brew install of php56 can't find php extensions

Tags: php, homebrew

I just did a brew install of php56.  Then wanted to enable some extensions like php_pdo_mysql and php_mysqli, so I went to my php.ini file and uncommented the relevant lines, for example: `extension=php_mysqli.so`
But for some reason which I try to start php I get the error:
`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_mysql.so'`

I don't have such a directory on my system.  I tried to find the correct location of my php extensions, but couldn't find it.  I believe I must have them since typing `php -m` gives a list of all the zend modules I need.  I do seem to have a folder `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212` which only has 3 extensions in it, but when I tried to replace the extension directory section of my php-config file with this file, calling phpinfo() still listed the old missing directory.  Any help in figuring out how to have php access these missing extensions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I've well understood this [Github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1620), you should remove `opcache` reference from your `php.ini` (you will were it is located by doing `php -i | grep ini`, and it's probably in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`).
I commented these two lines :

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=0
```

And to retrieve `opcache`, `brew rm php56 && brew install php56 --enable-opcache` should do the job ! (though I'm not sure )